# Delete array graphically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this, and well, need help.
I'm trying to put my information into an array that's going to be shown and always be able to **grow**. I need help deleting specific entries into it, either by searching for one or by pointing a mouse and deleting it,

Is there any nice easy way to do it?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sv">
<body>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">  
</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Förnamn" id="name" autofocus>
    <input type="date" id="pnummer" autofocus>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Efternamn" id="enamn" autofocus>
    <input type="button" value="mata in" onclick="register()">
    <input type="button" value="visa" onclick="show()">

<script type="text/javascript">
array=[]

function register() 
{ 
 var fnamn = document.getElementById("name").value;
 var enamn = document.getElementById("enamn").value;
 var pnummer = document.getElementById("pnummer").value;
 var p1 = new Person(fnamn,pnummer,enamn);
 array.push(p1);

}
function Person(fnamn, pnummer, enamn)
{
 this.fnamn=fnamn;
 this.pnummer=pnummer;
 this.enamn=enamn;
 this.visa=function()
 {
  var panel ="Förnamn:"+" "+this.fnamn+" "+"Efternamn:"+" "+this.enamn+" "+"Personnummer:"+" "+this.pnummer+"<br>";
  return panel;
 }
}

function show(){
 var showperson=document.getElementById("new");
 showperson.innerHTML=""; 
 var i=0;
 while (array.length>i)
  {
  showperson.innerHTML+=array[i].visa()
  i++;
  }
}
</script>

<p id="new"></p>
<div id="panel"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: arrays in js are dynamic from the get-go, meaning they can grow as you wish. As far as deleting elements from the array, checkout [Array#splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you're trying to do or what some of those words mean but is this what you're trying to do?

```js
var peopleTracker = {};
var peopleCounter = 0;

function addPerson()
{
    // get the values
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value.trim();
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value.trim();
    var birthday = document.getElementById("birthday").value.trim();
    
    // make sure none are blank
    if(firstName == "" || lastName == "" || birthday == "") return;
    
    // give each person an ID so we can remove them later
    var personID = ++peopleCounter;
  
    peopleTracker[personID] = {
        "firstName" : firstName,
        "lastName" : lastName,
        "birthday" : birthday
    };
    
    // add the person to the table
    var row = document.getElementById("peopleList").insertRow();
    row.insertCell().innerText = firstName;
    row.insertCell().innerText = lastName;
    row.insertCell().innerText = birthday;
    row.insertCell().innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="removePerson(this.parentNode.parentNode, ' + personID + '); return false">remove</a>';
}

// delete a user from the tracker and remove the row
function removePerson(row, personID)
{
    delete peopleTracker[personID];
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sv">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>the dingo ate my baby</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName" autofocus>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Sur Name" id="lastName" autofocus>
    <input type="date" id="birthday" autofocus>
    <input type="button" value="Add Person" onclick="addPerson()">
    <br /><br />
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Sur Name</th>
            <th>Birthday</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="peopleList"></tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

A few thoughts:

- If you're going to use an array to delete then you're going to need to use some unique ID to be able to find the person you want to delete. You cannot use the array `index` because that will change as you remove people from the array.
- By using an object to store the users you can delete by using a unique ID that changes for each user added.

Answer (score 0):

I jQuery is an option, you could find the index of your clicked `<div>` and delete the element with something like the following function:

```
$( "div.someIdYouGiveIt" ).click(function() {
  var index = $( "div.someClassYouGiveIt" ).index( this );
  array.splice(index, 1);
});
```